# video not getting in ie and mozilla in bootstrap framework

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, video, cross-browser

We have a site i am using   video background  i was getting that video in chrome  but in Mozilla  and ie9  i wasn't not getting that video  i am using bootstrap framework. I don't how to implement that can any help for this? Here's the website link  [Click here to see website](http://haider.santabantathegreat.com/html/)

```
<body>
<!-- =========================
     PRE LOADER       
============================== -->
<div class="preloader">
  <div class="status">&nbsp;</div>
</div> 


<!-- =========================
     HEADER   
============================== -->
<header class="header" id="home">    

<!-- COLOR OVER IMAGE -->
<div class="color-overlay"> <!-- To make header full screen. Use .full-screen class with color overlay. Example: <div class="color-overlay full-screen">  -->

    <!-- STICKY NAVIGATION -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse bs-docs-nav navbar-fixed-top sticky-navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">

                <!-- LOGO ON STICKY NAV BAR -->
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#kane-navigation">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
               <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img alt="" src="images/logo023.png" class="showlogo"></a>


            </div>

            <!-- NAVIGATION LINKS -->
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="kane-navigation">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right main-navigation">
                    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>  
                    <li><a href="#features">Sorrento Histology</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#brief2">Sorrento Overview</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#download">Products in Development</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#profile">Company Profile</a></li>
                    <!-- <li><a href="#screenshot-section">Screenshots</a></li> -->
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- /END CONTAINER -->
    </div> <!-- /END STICKY NAVIGATION -->
```

Regards
madu